Would it be out of style to start a history book with a poem I wrote?
Multiple primary sources I’ve consulted made use of the same metaphor to describe the Roman genos – an orchard of olive trees. I wrote a poem about it. I don't plan for the reader to understand what I meant in the poem, I want my conclusion to be a reiteration of the poem in a non-metaphorical form, when I will have proven every section of it. I don't know if it is a good idea or if I could integrate it well at the beginning of a book.

What does genos mean?

@Ben it was a term used alongside ethnos by Byzantine writers to describe the Roman "race" or "species"

How long is the poem, and is understanding it important to the reader, or just a sort of artistic flourish? I think if it's short (like a verse or two) and you put it at the start, but away from the opening text proper (e.g. on a prior page, on its own), and in italics or something, readers will easily recognise it as such and not worry too much about understanding it.

@komodosp the poem is about a page and a half long. The poem is not that important, I wrote it to give a metaphorical explanation to my conclusion, which I thought might help to understand. I should probably write it after my conclusion. Ex: “in other words . . .”

What sort of book is this?  A popular, easy-to-read book for a general audience, or an authoritative, academic tome for experts, or something in between?

@gidds I would say it is something in between but leaning more towards a tome for experts

I don't think it is a good idea to start a factual book with something people do not understand.
Starting with something difficult to understand in a fiction book is bad enough; but in a lesson book, you immediately alienate the reader that wants to learn, because the first thing they read is something they do not understand, and cannot parse.

Am I supposed to memorize this poem?


Is this something I should be able to understand?


Is this book over my head?

The best way to start a history book is with a literal story from history, something engaging they are supposed to learn anyway. Perhaps some surprising strategy, and play up the strangeness of the strategy.
There is the famous picture of George Washington crossing the Delaware. It was extremely dangerous, the currents were strong, it was freezing. Why is it so famous and heroic? Why did Washington take the risk?
He did that because it was the only way to make a surprise attack on the Hessians, fighting for the British, in Trenton New Jersey. And it paid off, the attack was successful, a crucial victory and a turning point in the war, and news of the victory boosted the morale of all the American troops.
This picture represents a crucial turning point in the war that led to American Independence. Now surely, Washington was not standing in the boat! That is just symbolic of his leadership of the Army to victory.
Whatever history you are writing, start your book with something that will capture the student's imagination. Some crucial success or crucial mistake.
History is full of stories, and we love stories. Start with a good one.
Do not start with a puzzle nobody can figure out, that is just discouraging.

Yeah, you're right, I think I forgot about making what im writting accessible. Maybe I'll put it at the end as some sort of poetic conclusion once every detail has been explained.

I think that is a good idea, ending with a poem that summarizes your thesis would be an interesting finish.
